# Rails 6.1 where.missing across self joins

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Assume the following MTI approach:

- `Node` is a hierarchical system for `Category` and `Thing`
- `Node` has a self-join `parent` (inverse of `children`)
- `Category` can contain `Things` as `members`
- Each `Category` and `Thing` belong to one `Node`
- `Node` has a boolean field `deleted`

```rb
class Node
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Node', optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'parent_id', dependent: 'nullify', inverse_of: 'parent'

  has_one :category_instance, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Category' # For Category Nodes, otherwise nil
  has_one :thing_instance, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'Thing' # For Thing Nodes, otherwise nil

  belongs_to :category, optional: true
end

class Category
  belongs_to :node, optional: false
  has_many :members, class_name: 'Node', inverse_of: :category, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end

class Thing
  belongs_to :node, optional: false
end
```

For example, the following hierarchy can be achived:

- category1

  - category2

    - thingA
    - thingB

      - thingC

Where category2 is the child of category1 (implemented via: category2's node (node2) is the child of category1's node: `node2.parent_id == node1.id`) and thingA's node's (nodeA) category is category2: `thingA.node.category_id == node2.id`.

I'm looking for the two queries in the most Railsy way possible:

#### Query about members

"Give me all Categories whose Node is not deleted, containing no members who's Node is not deleted".

So this would be something like (Pseudocode) `categories.nondeleted.where.missing(non_deleted_members).

The special case where thingB would be deleted and thingC is not deleted can be omitted, we're only talking about direct members.

#### Query about children

"Give me all non-deleted Nodes containing any non-deleted children"

#### Why where.missing does not work

I'm using Rails 6.1. The statement `where.missing` cannot be used because it generates queries containing the word `node` both for parent/category and child/member, leading to wrong results containing e.g. deleted parents.

The DB used is MySQL 10.4.

Comment: Can you give us an actual example of the data and the expected result? Its still hard to figure out exactly what it is that you're after.

Comment: yeah, not easily reproducible without the model definition, and example rows.  Have you got examples of the queries that you have tried, so that this doesn't look like an examination question?

Comment: While I cannot share the code, here's a workaround that might even be considered a solution, but it's not elegant: in `Category`: `scope :without_nondeleted_children, -> { where.not(id: Node.nondeleted.pluck(:parent_id).uniq) }`, then `Category.nondeleted.without_nondeleted_children`